# Finding smith normal form of $x-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$
 A = 
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &0 &0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0& 0\\
-2&-2   & 2 & 1 \\
1& 1&-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$
I want to find Smith normal form of $x-A$ I know that the minimal polynomial is $x^2(x-1)^2$. I am diagonalizing the matrix using elementary row and column operations and I have got 
$$ \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0   & x^2 & 0 \\
0& 0& 0 & -(x-1)^2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$
Have I calculated this correctly? (I checked several times and could not find any calculation mistake)
This is diagonal but not Smith normal as $x^2 |-(x-1)^2$ is contradiction. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply haven't finished the process. If you premultiply your matrix
$$ \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0   & x^2 & 0 \\
0& 0& 0 & -(x-1)^2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$
by the unimodular matrix
$$ \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0   & -x+2 & x^2-2x-1 \\
0& 0& x^2-2x+1 & -x^3+2x^2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$
and postmultiply it by the unimodular matrix
$$ \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0   & -x+2 & -x^4+4x^3-4x^2+1 \\
0& 0& 1 & -x^3-2x^2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$
you end up with the matrix
$$ \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0&0   & 1 & 0 \\
0& 0& 0 & x^4-2x^3+x^2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad, $$
which is therefore the Smith normal form of your original.

Comment: How did you get those matrices

Comment: Oh I got it. Just played around with that 2 by 2 matrix.

Comment: @mathemather Well done. You can actually deduce what the Smith normal form must be without going through the rigmarole necessary to find the two unimodular matrices, though.  From the general theory it follows that the third elementary divisor must be the gcd of $\ x^2\ $ and $\ \left(x-1\right)^2\ $, and the fourth must be their product.